# How to optimize this if-else statement used for tagging sports from title

Tags: php, performance, optimization, laravel, laravel-4

So I'm trying to auto categorize sports from the event title.

It's working fine, however i think there should be a better and more reliable method to do this. And for some sports like (`FIFA`) it outputs its type as `NCAA` instead of `FIFA` same thing with `MMA` and 1-2 more.

Here's my code (**Note:** `str_contains` is a laravel helper function I'm using).

```
$strTitle = strtolower($title);
      if(str_contains($strTitle, 'mlb') || str_contains($strTitle, 'baseball')) {
        $category = 'Baseball';
        $type = 'MLB';
      } elseif (str_contains($strTitle, 'nba') || str_contains($strTitle, 'fiba') || str_contains($strTitle, 'basketball') || str_contains($strTitle, 'wnba')) {
        $category = 'Basketball';
        $type = (str_contains($strTitle, 'nba')) ? 'NBA':
                  (str_contains($strTitle, 'fiba')) ? 'FIBA':
                    (str_contains($strTitle, 'wnba')) ? 'WNBA':'Basketball';
      } elseif (str_contains($strTitle, 'nhl') || str_contains($strTitle, 'hockey')) {
        $category = 'Hockey';
        $type = 'NHL';
      } elseif (str_contains($strTitle, 'nascar') || str_contains($strTitle, 'formula one') || str_contains($strTitle, 'gp2') || str_contains($strTitle, 'gp3') || str_contains($strTitle, 'motogp') || str_contains($strTitle, 'moto2') || str_contains($strTitle, 'moto3') || str_contains($strTitle, 'f1')) {
        $category = 'Motor Sport';
        $type = (str_contains($strTitle, 'nascar')) ? 'NASCAR':
                  (str_contains($strTitle, 'gp2')) ? 'GP2':
                    (str_contains($strTitle, 'gp3')) ? 'GP3':
                      (str_contains($strTitle, 'motogp')) ? 'MotoGP':
                        (str_contains($strTitle, 'moto2')) ? 'Moto2':
                          (str_contains($strTitle, 'moto3')) ? 'Moto3':
                            (str_contains($strTitle, 'f1') || str_contains($strTitle, 'formula one')) ? 'F1':'Motor Sport';
      } elseif (str_contains($strTitle, 'nfl') || str_contains($strTitle, 'afl') || str_contains($strTitle, 'welsh premier league') || str_contains($strTitle, 'fox college') || str_contains($strTitle, 'football') || str_contains($strTitle, 'serie') || str_contains($strTitle, 'soccer') || str_contains($strTitle, 'fifa') || str_contains($strTitle, 'ncaa')) {
        $category = 'Football';
        $type = (str_contains($strTitle, 'nfl')) ? 'NFL':
                  (str_contains($strTitle, 'fifa')) ? 'FIFA':
                    (str_contains($strTitle, 'afl')) ? 'AFL':
                      (str_contains($strTitle, 'welsh premier league')) ? 'Welsh Premier League':
                        (str_contains($strTitle, 'ncaa')) ? 'NCAA':'Football';
      } elseif (str_contains($strTitle, 'tennis')) {
        $category = 'Tennis';
        $type = 'Tennis';
      }  elseif (str_contains($strTitle, 'golf')) {
        $category = 'Golf';
        $type = 'Golf';
      } elseif (str_contains($strTitle, 'rugby') || str_contains($strTitle, 'nrl')) {
        $category = 'Rugby';
        $type = (str_contains($strTitle, 'nrl')) ? 'NRL' : 'Rugby';
      } elseif (str_contains($strTitle, 'sailing') || str_contains($strTitle, 'america\'s cup')) {
        $category = 'Water Sport';
        $type = 'Sailing';
      } elseif (str_contains($strTitle, 'boxing') || str_contains($strTitle, 'fight night') || str_contains($strTitle, 'fighting') || str_contains($strTitle, 'wwe') || str_contains($strTitle, 'smackdown') || str_contains($strTitle, 'raw') || str_contains($strTitle, 'wwe main event') || str_contains($strTitle, 'mma') || str_contains($strTitle, 'strikeforce') || str_contains($strTitle, 'tna')) {
        $category = 'Boxing';
        $type = (str_contains($strTitle, 'ufc')) ? 'UFC' :
                  (str_contains($strTitle, 'smackdown')) ? 'WWE Smackdown' :
                    (str_contains($strTitle, 'raw')) ? 'WWE RAW' :
                      (str_contains($strTitle, 'wwe main event')) ? 'WWE Main Event':
                        (str_contains($strTitle, 'wwe')) ? 'WWE':
                          (str_contains($strTitle, 'mma')) ? 'MMA':
                            (str_contains($strTitle, 'tna')) ? 'TNA':
                              (str_contains($strTitle, 'strikeforce')) ? 'Strikeforce':
                                (str_contains($strTitle, 'fight night')) ? 'Fight Night':
                                  (str_contains($strTitle, 'fighting')) ? 'Fighting':'Boxing';
      } elseif (str_contains($strTitle, 'cricket') || str_contains($strTitle, 'icc') || str_contains($strTitle, 'mcc') || str_contains($strTitle, 'odi') || str_contains($strTitle, 'ipl') || str_contains($strTitle, 't20') || str_contains($strTitle, 'twenty20')) {
        $category = 'Cricket';
        $type = (str_contains($strTitle, 'icc')) ? 'ICC' :
                  (str_contains($strTitle, 'mcc')) ? 'MCC' :
                    (str_contains($strTitle, 'odi')) ? 'ODI':
                      (str_contains($strTitle, 'ipl')) ? 'IPL':
                        (str_contains($strTitle, 't20')) ? 'T20':
                          (str_contains($strTitle, 'twenty20')) ? 'Twenty20':'Cricket';
      }
```

**Note 2:** This isn't the full code and not for all sports, just for the ones I have atm.

Comment: In my opinion, no fix, dump it, start from scratch with clear data structure.

Comment: But that's what idk..lol :P
I mean what other thing can i use, maybe if i get 1-2 lines of example on how i can do this same thing in better way, I'll continue from there.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a better way, unless you need to include some kind of near-miss spelling correction or heuristic choosing between ambiguous results. Then you need to pull out bigger guns.

Answer (score 2):

While a far from ideal solution, here's something I threw together that will yield the same results, with probably a similar performance hit (no idea, really, just a guess), that is **MUCH MUCH MUCH more readable**.

Before that, seriously: look at all your ternary conditionals. Does that seem like a good idea?!

#### Caveats

1. `str_contains()` uses PHP's `strpos()`, which is case sensitive. You'll need to either keep that in mind, or simply lowercase the whole string before searching/comparing.
2. Similarly, `strpos()` doesn't care if it finds strings *inside* other words/strings. So, for example, if the title contains "WNBA", the keyword "NBA" will match *first*, then this check will end, giving you unexpected results. You can fix this by listing your keywords from biggest, most specific first, to smallest, most ambiguous last.
3. Performance isn't too awful here unless you're using a crap ton of keywords (and I mean a crap ton). However, it's still possible that you could go through 10-20 sets of keywords without finding a match, just because of the order. I don't have a real good, immediate solution to this aside from use a text-based search software (e.g. Sphinx, Lucene, Solr, DB-based, etc.), but it's something to keep in mind.

---

```
// Define your sports and their keywords / human values.
// I use an array of objects (I like objects). This could be
// a JSON or XML feed, generated through an API or your DB.
// Doesn't matter. Just give the data you need to check against
// a structure, not just hardcoded into conditionals.
$sports = [
    (object) [
        'category'  => 'Baseball',
        'keywords'  => [
            'baseball'  => 'Baseball',
            'mlb'       => 'MLB'
        ],
    ],
    (object) [
        'category'  => 'Basketball',
        'keywords'  => [
            'basketball'    => 'Basketball',
            'nba'           => 'NBA',
            'fiba'          => 'FIBA',
            'wnba'          => 'WNBA',
        ],
    ],
    (object) [
        'category'  => 'Motor Sport',
        'keywords'  => [
            'nascar'    => 'NASCAR',
            'gp2'       => 'GP2',
            'gp3'       => 'GP3',
            'motogp'    => 'MotoGP',
            'moto2'     => 'Moto2',
            'moto3'     => 'Moto3',
            'f1'        => 'Formula 1'
        ],
    ],
];

$title = strtolower("Rookie player Cryode injured in bizarre FIBA accident.");

$sport_category = null;
$sport_type = null;

// Step 1: Loop each sport.
foreach ($sports as $sport)
{
    // Step 2: At least one keyword matched. Let's see which one.
    foreach ($sport->keywords as $key_search => $key_type)
    {
        if (str_contains($title, $key_search))
        {
            // Step 3: We've found the matching keyword.
            // Define the info we need from it...
            $sport_category = $sport->category;
            $sport_type = $key_type;

            // ... then break BOTH loops.
            break 2;
        }
    }
}

// Step 4: Check for no matches here by seeing
// if the category or type is still null.
// Or, initially set vars to default values.

var_dump($sport_category, $sport_type);
```